# How can you call a function which is defined in app.py, from HTML template rendered by app.py, on flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

app.py ->

```
def pretty_date(time=False):
    from datetime import datetime
    now = datetime.now()
    if type(time) is int:
        diff = now - datetime.fromtimestamp(time)
    elif isinstance(time,datetime):
        diff = now - time
    elif not time:
        diff = now - now
    second_diff = diff.seconds
    day_diff = diff.days

    if day_diff < 0:
        return ''

    if day_diff == 0:
        if second_diff < 10:
            return "just now"
        if second_diff < 60:
            return str(second_diff) + " seconds ago"
        if second_diff < 120:
            return "a minute ago"
        if second_diff < 3600:
            return str(second_diff / 60) + " minutes ago"
        if second_diff < 7200:
            return "an hour ago"
        if second_diff < 86400:
            return str(second_diff / 3600) + " hours ago"
    if day_diff == 1:
        return "Yesterday"
    if day_diff < 7:
        return str(day_diff) + " days ago"
    if day_diff < 31:
        return str(day_diff / 7) + " weeks ago"
    if day_diff < 365:
        return str(day_diff / 30) + " months ago"
    return str(day_diff / 365) + " years ago"
```

And HTML Template ->

```
{{pretty_date(post.time)}}
```

Gives an error

> UndefinedError: 'pretty_date' is undefined

Is there a way I can be able to call it? The same app.py renders the html page btw.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you have to pass anything (functions, variables, ect.) you want to use in your HTML code in the `render_template` call via keyword arguments.

Example: `render_template("main.html", pretty_date=pretty_date)`

Answer (score 0):

You can register functions in your app object to make them globally available to your jinja templates:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.jinja_env.globals.update(pretty_date=pretty_date)
```

Now any template can use `{{ pretty_date() }}`.

You can also pass a function (or any other object type) in your call to `render_template` but this needs to be done for every view, so if you want to call the same function from multiple templates you're better off registering it globally.